# Can I wire 3 lights to one switch as illustrated by this mock up diagram?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I'm looking at lighting a kitchen in a wood cabin and to try and make the wiring (which will sit on the outside of the ceiling) as neat as possible, I'm wondering if I can wire 3 separate lights in the fashion I've illustrated below (taking an illustration that was done for 2 lights and trying to add a third, but not in a daisy chain fashion).

Illustration/diagram:

[image: Possible wiring]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yep that works as drawn.

Answer (score 4):

People use black and white because they only sell NM cable in black-white or black-white-red. We *certainly wish* we could use more illustrative colors.

Let's recolor the wires to indicate their actual *function*.  You can do the same thing with colored tape.

[image]

With red being switched-hot, it seems clear you are doing the right thing.

- Lamps should get switched-hot and neutral *check*
- switches should get hot and switched-hot *check*
- neutral should be available in the switch box for future smart switches *check*.

Looks right to me.

Comment: In the US, isn't black _a_ normal color for the hot, while white is neutral and bare/green is ground? Red is _also_ hot, but no more indicative of hot than black, is it? Why insist on coloring the wires "to indicate their actual function"? I'm not a trained electrician by any means, so I'm missing something on why red is better in this diagram than the black was.

Comment: @FreeMan In this particular example, this circuit is fairly simple, so. your brain cells can handle the only ambiguous area, in the switch box... but just wait til a 3-way is involved. **Or two!**

Comment: That makes sense. I was just wondering why you made the effort on this one. ;)